# Data Access in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the recommended way of creating a Data Access layer in real-life ASP.NET MVC applications? Is it EF? Ef Code First? NHibernate? Any other idea?

Thank you & regards

Comment: .NET ORMs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no recommend way.

I prefer EF Code First for doing this because

- the Sourcecode is very clean and easy to read
- It is easy to simple change the connectionstring and generate a new database if not already exists
- easy to migrate your Database if your Model has changed (no need to recreate the Database) using **EntityFramework.SqlMigrations**
- if your Database already exists you can use the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to generate the Models and Database context from your existing Database

Answer (score 3):

It all depends of your need:

- NHibernate is a more mature ORM with a big community
- Entity Framework is now getting very well supported and you can find also great information ([check Julie Lerman blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/))

Both support code generation from database.

Code first: allows you to create your database schema from your domain models. This is great if you don't want to bother with database. NHibernate can do it also.

To help you decide which way to use Entity Framework

[image]

[Source](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/model-first-database-first-or-code-first-ndash-update-to-data-points-column/)

There are many other great ORM:

[Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)

[Stackoverflow's ORM Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) if performance is an important criteria there is a small benchmark on the site

Answer (score 1):

If you're partial to the MSFT tooling and wanting to be "modern", then EF Code First is probably the place to start.  One example worth perusing: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery .

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Model First because it allows me the most freedom to design and implement in my opinion.  It also makes it very easy to change the database design.

Comment: I like model first also, but I think we're in the minority (not that the majority is necessarily correct). I think you can benefit from doing some work via Model first.

Answer (score 1):

There is none,  stackoverflow is full of people who have gone down the various routes, so you can get help no matter which choice you make.

Best advice,  try doing a few small exploratory webs using a couple of approaches which seem to stand out.

Comment: Unfortunately the real obstacles doesn't tend to show up on small testprojects but on real project with real data.

Comment: no, but most ways have various obstacles.... nothings perfect,  but it does tell you whether the style of development seems to match what you want.  But yes, there are complications that creep in!

Comment: It's still a good idea to do proto-types with each - even tho you won't uncover many of the problems you hit in a real app.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC gurus (the people who wrote MVC) at MS all seem to use Entity Framework at the moment. having said that you can use any ORM (or really any data access tech you want) as MVC doesnt actually specify anything at all about the way you access data

Comment: 1. Not all MVC folks at MS use EF exclusively. 2. Not all MVC gurus work for MS (in fact most don't). You are correct we don't tell folks what to use.

Answer (score -1):

Try LINQ, most MVC products I see make use of LINQ.

Comment: LINQ is a tool for interacting with a data access layer.  It doesn't create the layer itself.

Comment: How robust EF Code First for real-life heavy usage websites?

Comment: LINQ is a programming model that introduces queries as a first-class concept into any
 Microsoft .NET language.